# Javascript - succinct way to assign another value to variable if first value is not truthy

Tags: javascript, syntax, syntactic-sugar

I have a function that may return a value or may return null and I want to assign it to a variable. So at the moment I've got

```js
someVar = (someFun())
  ? someFun()
  : "foo";
```

Is there a shorterer way of doing it, where I don't have to call the function twice, or add an extra variable like:

```js
funResult = someFun();
someVar = (funResult)
  ? funResult
  : "foo";
```

Basically, something like:

```
someVar = someFun() | "foo"
```

Comment: TIL what "null coalescing" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way is

```
someVar = someFun() || "foo";
```

The `||` operator will yield the value of the left-hand expression if it's truthy. If not, it will move on to evaluate the right-hand side, and return its value.

For those unfamiliar with the term "truthy", in JavaScript it means values that are not considered by the language to be implicitly `false`. The implicitly `false` values are `0`, `NaN`, `false` (of course), `""`, `null`, and `undefined`. Any reference to an object, even if it's completely empty, is considered to be "truthy".

In your specific example, the `||` approach is to be preferred because it means you only call `someFun()` once.

Comment: You might want to emphasise that "not truthy" is more than just `null`.

Comment: @Bergi I thought about that but the OP seemed to "get it"; however for posterity that's definitely a good idea.

Comment: I knew that syntax was familiar. I was just missing a |